# Where is the MOQ documentation?

Tags: c#, .net, testing, mocking, moq

Where can I find comprehensive documentation for MOQ? I'm just starting with mocking and am having difficulty getting my head around it. I've read through all the links at http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart but can't seem to find a tutorial or gentle introduction.

I have also looked briefly at Rhino Mocks but found it very confusing.

---

Yes - I read Stephen Walthers article - very helpful. I also went through the links. I can't seem to watch the video at <strike>http://www.bestechvideos.com/2008/06/08/dimecasts-net-introduction-to-mocking-with-moq</strike> <sup>[broken link]</sup>

Specifically I am trying to determine whether an event was raised from the mocked class. I can't get the example for events on the QuickStarts page to compile. On the google groups, Daniel explained that CreateEventHandler can only handle an event of type `EventHandler<TEventArgs>`, but even then I can't get the code to compile.

More specifically I have a class that implements `INotifyChanged`.

```
public class Entity : INotifyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    public int Id 
      { 
          get {return _id;}
          set {
                 _id = value;
                 OnPropertyChanged("Id");
              }
      }

     protected void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
      {
         if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
 etc .....    
}
```

How do I mock the class to test whether the `PropertyChanged` event was fired? I can't rewrite the event to `public event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs>` becuase I get this error:

> Error 1   'CoreServices.Notifier' does not implement interface member  System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged'. 'CoreServices.Notifier.PropertyChanged' cannot implement 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler'.

Comment: The error shown is a visual studio/compiler bug. Just remove everything from the bin folder and rebuild.

Comment: The link to *Introduction to Mocking with Moq* in my answer is fixed.

Comment: the link is broken (again)

Comment: Agreed the Moq homepage is really really bad for people new to the framework.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters or somebody else reopen this question, please

Comment: @anatol: someone first edit it to be on-topic then.

Comment: The current rationale given for it being closed is "We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. You can edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations.", for the benefit of those without close/reopen privileges.

Answer (score 39):

Moq's latest documentation is now available at github wiki page:

https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Previously they were on Google Code. As well as the wiki and other online resources, there's full documentation in Windows .CHM help-file format included in the [Moq binary download](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) linked from [the Moq homepage](https://github.com/Moq/).

Comment: Direct link to latest (4.0.10827) release: http://moq.googlecode.com/files/Moq.4.0.10827.Final.zip

Comment: Very quaint and platform specific, but quite functional!

Comment: there not enough details to call that *documentation*

Answer (score 16):

Have you watched [Introduction to Mocking with Moq](http://dimecasts.net/Content/WatchEpisode/8)?  It's an introductory overview of using Moq and is intended for those who are new to either mocking in general, or the Moq framework itself.

Answer (score 5):

Have you read the linked pages at https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart ?
for example [this one](http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/archive/2008/06/11/tdd-introduction-to-moq.aspx) (probably moved to [stephen walthers personal blog](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/06/12/tdd-introduction-to-moq.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to determine whether an event was raised from the mocked
>   class.

Are you? Or are you trying to determine if the `Id` property was set? Remember, by default a mock has no behavior. It's not raising notification events.

I'd do:

```
const int ExpectedId = 123;
mockEntity.VerifySet(x => x.Id = ExpectedId);
```

This assumes that Entity implements an interface; one example:

```
public interface IKeyedEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

That said, if `Entity` is a [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) with no interesting behavior I would neither implement an interface (other than `INotifyChanged`) nor mock it. Test with an actual `Entity` instance (just don't use a database). Reserve mocking for services and complex dependencies.

For more Moq features, see

[Old style imperative mocks vs moq functional specifications](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/old-style-imperative-mocks-vs-moq-functional-specifications/)
and
[Mock.Of - how to specify behavior? (thread)](http://groups.google.com/group/moqdisc/browse_thread/thread/7c0477e3f4e6f400?pli=1). I also posted my own example of [Moq v4 functional specifications](http://www.truewill.net/myblog/index.php/2011/04/20/moq_v4_functional_specifications).